# Como debugear en javascript ? especificamente en angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Recientemente me ha pasado que tenia un error , llamado 
**EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters ...**

Buscando encontre que posiblemente era por los barrels , pues cuando intentaba ver la fuente del error desde mi consola , solo me salia ese mensaje , y no tenia forma de ver donde encontrar el error, segui lo que me recomendaron tratar de no usar los barrels , elimine todos los index.ts y adapte , estuve alrededor de 2 hs en este error.

Luego me puse a compara un commit anterior par a ver cual era la diferencia,y resulta que era porque en un barrel.ts el de servicios , importe 2 veces el mismo servicio , borre 1 y todo corrio perfectamente.

Es un error que le puede pasar como un ; en otros lenguajes como c/c++ , pero en ese caso el compilador te avisa , uso jit , para compilar,para evitar este tipo de cosas  ,que herramientas para debugear en tiempo de compilacion para js existen?

Answer (score 1):

Pues depende, creo q para js o ts no aplica el caso de debugger, ya que debugger es cuando intesta correr tu aplicacion probando cada elemento o clase construida de modo que al haber un error se detenga el funcionamiento. Creo q para tu caso lo que necesitas es algo como un `linter` de modo que puedas ver los posibles erorres de syntax en js.

Pudieras usar `JShint para js, o JShint-linter`.. Si usas un editor de texto como `atom o sublime` puedes encontrar estos paquetes e instalarlos. Son de muy buena ayuda al momento de programar front - end. Saludos

Comment: Gracias amigo , el problema esque ya uso linter para los errores de sintaxis , sin embargo hay cosas que en angular2 no me reconoce ,no tengo manera de ver ciertos errores, por ejemplo una doble importacion no me tira el error en webpack.